# read a text file to QStringList

Tags: qt, file

I have a text file. I need to read it to a QStringList. there are no line seperators. I mean each line in the text file is in a new line. So is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: In this case, the newline character '\n' is your line separator.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume that every line should be a separate string in the list. Use [QTextStream::readLine()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#readLine) in a cycle and on each step append the returned value to the QStringList. Like this:

```
QStringList stringList;
QFile textFile;
//... (open the file for reading, etc.)
QTextStream textStream(&textFile);
while (true)
{
    QString line = textStream.readLine();
    if (line.isNull())
        break;
    else
        stringList.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
    QFile TextFile;
    //Open file for reading
    QStringList SL;

    while(!TextFile.atEnd())
    SL.append(TextFile.readLine());
```

Answer (score 4):

If the file isn't too big, read the whole content into a `QString` and then [`split()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qstring.html#split) it into a `QStringList`.

I like using the QRegExp version to handle linefeed from different platforms:

```
QStringList sList = s.split(QRegExp("(\\r\\n)|(\\n\\r)|\\r|\\n"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like my code to be fully indented/paranthesized with obvious variable names (they may take longer to type but are much easier to debug) so would do the following (but changing "myTextFile" and "myStringList" to more sensible names, such as "employeeListTextFile")

```
QFile myTextFile;
QStringList myStringList;

if (!myTextFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "Error opening file", myTextFile.errorString());
}
else
{  
    while(!myTextFile.atEnd())
    {
        myStringList.append(myTextFile.readLine());
    }

    myTextFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code reads the file

```
         QFile File("/file_path");
        if(!File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly));
          {
              qDebug("Error");
         } 
        QTextStream in(&File);

    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        qDebug()<<ReadAll;
        ReadAll=in.readAll();

    }
    File.close();
```

Now the file is closed, now split the new line i.e \n here \r is carriage return

```
    List= ReadAll.split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```